# How can i config authentication in port azure?

Tags: laravel, laravel-socialite, azure-authentication

**I am making an account login function using Microsoft Office. Currently I am using azure portal to do that but it doesn't allow to use URI like this: http://myteam.local/ What do I have to do to make it work?**

> I am using laravel, socialiteproviders/microsoft

Comment: What is preventing you from using myteam.local as redirect url?

Comment: @MaartenDev Hi, When i access Portal Azure -> Authentication and add URI: myteam.local 
But Portal Azure messages: Must use HTTPS, just use http ://localhost

Comment: Is this for local development or are you deploying this app to an internal network?

Comment: Yes. I deployed on heroku